# Access Find, Match and Replace

Tags: ms-access

I have an MS-Access query that I am trying to design with little luck. I have 2 columns...one of check numbers and one of invoice numbers. For every check number there has to be an invoice number. The columns look like this...

```
Check#          Invoice#
012564          
012564          PC0935
012564          PC0935
012564
```

I need to fill in the Invoice# wherever it is missing on the check. 
I can get it to work as an index/match with a vlooup in Excel but I need to be able to do this in Access.

I have tried dlookups with replace but no luck. I am not looking for the absolute answer but some ideas in the general direction would be most appreciated!

I have no knowledge of VBA and very limited SQL.

Comment: You've not given us much to go on as far as how you want the Invoice number completed - for all Check numbers that = 012564 and Invoice is Null then enter PC0935?  That would be `UPDATE Table1 SET Invoice = 'PC0935' WHERE Check = '012564' AND Invoice Is Null`

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook: I apologize for not being clear. It would not only be for that check number. There are multiples lines of data and within that there is, at a minumum, 1 set that has the complete check:invoice association. I am trying to make sure that for every instance of a check number the invoice is filled in. Not sure I am being clear on this though.

Comment: ok, so you want the table updated so that each `Check#` entry has a corresponding `Invoice#` entry and there will _always_ be at least one entry in that table that does have the 'Check# ~ Invoice#` pairing so use that pairing to complete the empty records?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my comment that you want the table updated so that each Check# entry has a corresponding Invoice# entry and there will always be at least one entry in that table that does have the 'Check# ~ Invoice#` pairing so use that pairing to complete the empty records.

e.g. Check 012564 has Invoice# PC0935, and 012565 has PC0939 in at least one record.  We just need to complete the blanks for those Check numbers.
All records will have a Check #.

This SQL should do it:

```
UPDATE Table1 T1 INNER JOIN Table1 T2 ON T1.Check = T2.Check
SET T1.Invoice = T2.Invoice
WHERE T1.Invoice IS NULL AND NOT T2.Invoice Is Null
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and help. Your solution would probably work if it were separate tables but these are 2 columns in the same table. Exporting to Excel with the index/match might be my only solution. Working on another idea with a new table.

Comment: The SQL is using the same table on both sides of the join. Both T1 & T2 are alias names for Table1.